# is this dtd right for the xml file?

Tags: php, xml, xsd, dtd

I have this xml file:

data_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE allproperty SYSTEM "data_out.dtd">
<allproperty>
    <aproperty>
      <postcode>ha15rs</postcode> 
      <price>250</price> 
      <imagefilename>home2.gif</imagefilename> 
      <visits>2</visits> 
    </aproperty>
    <aproperty>
      <postcode>ha36gs</postcode> 
      <price>150</price> 
      <imagefilename>home3.gif</imagefilename> 
      <visits>1</visits> 
    </aproperty>
    <aproperty>
      <postcode>ha27se</postcode> 
      <price>300</price> 
      <imagefilename>home4.gif</imagefilename> 
      <visits>4</visits> 
    </aproperty>
    <aproperty>
      <postcode>ha4678</postcode> 
      <price>200</price> 
      <imagefilename>home5.gif</imagefilename> 
      <visits>5</visits> 
    </aproperty>
</allproperty>
```

a DTD file

data_out.dtd

```
<!ELEMENT aproperty (postcode,price,imagefilename,visits)>
<!ELEMENT postcode (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT imagefilename (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT visits (#PCDATA)>
```

I keep getting a error when I do check "saying the `allproperty` is not declared"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare allproperly in the DTD as well

```
<!ELEMENT allproperty (aproperty+)>
<!ELEMENT aproperty (postcode,price,imagefilename,visits)>
<!ELEMENT postcode (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT imagefilename (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT visits (#PCDATA)>
```

Comment: thanks i did that, now im getting `this Element allproperty content does not follow the DTD, expecting (aproperty), got (aproperty aproperty aproperty aproperty)` thanks +1 from me

Comment: @getaway: sorry forgot the `+`